# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable CircleCI

Tags: python, python-3.x, circleci

I'm trying to make this bit of code in my config.yml file work through CircleCI:

```
cd backend
pip install pipenv
pipenv install
```

When uploading to circleci, I get the following for this section, everything else passes:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2020.5.28)

Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.21)

Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (20.1.1)

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (46.4.0)

Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.4)

Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv) (2020.4.5.1)

Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.0)

Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.1.3)

Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)

Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)

Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.15.0)

Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (3.1.0)

Creating a virtualenv for this project…

Pipfile: /home/circleci/cyber-dive/Cyber-Dive-App/backend/Pipfile

Using /usr/local/bin/python3 (3.7.7) to create virtualenv…

created virtual environment CPython3.7.7.final.0-64 in 506ms

    creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/circleci/cyber-dive/Cyber-Dive-App/backend/.venv, clear=False, global=False)

  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/circleci/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)

  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator



Virtualenv location: /home/circleci/cyber-dive/Cyber-Dive-App/backend/.venv

Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (9ef944)…

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>

    sys.exit(cli())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__

    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main

    rv = self.invoke(ctx)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke

    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke

    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke

    return callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func

    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke

    return callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func

    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install

    editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install

    keep_outdated=keep_outdated

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init

    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 809, in do_install_dependencies

    deps_list = list(lockfile.get_requirements(dev=dev, only=requirements))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/lockfile.py", line 272, in get_requirements

    yield Requirement.from_pipfile(k, v)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 1183, in from_pipfile

    r = VCSRequirement.from_pipfile(name, pipfile)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 897, in from_pipfile

    return cls(**creation_args)

  File "<attrs generated init 3bab60f45f8eb7fe6e20ab91412def0e78d5dff6>", line 31, in __init__

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 706, in get_link

    extras=self.extras,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/utils.py", line 100, in build_vcs_link

    return create_link(uri)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/utils.py", line 40, in create_link

    return Link(link)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable


Exited with code exit status 1 

CircleCI received exit code 1 
`

When trying to run these tasks locally, here is what I get in my terminal after pipenv install:
ValueError: Path not found or generated: WindowsPath('c:/program files/git/mingw64/bin')
```

I have been googling my brains out with this and I've got nothing. The path it specifies in the ValueError does exist on my computer and I currently have Python 3.8.2. I also have 3.7.7 installed as listed in my programs. Please help because I am stumped.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2871#issuecomment-427336362) seems to suggest `pipenv` won't work unless you have pip 18.0, but you have pip > 20.0. What if you pin `pip`?

Comment: See also [this solution in the same thread](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2871#issuecomment-427425841)

Comment: I am seeing the same thing on circleci since yesterday, pip 19 and 20 were working well (and they are still locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok found the issue, it appears that on 2020-05-28 was released a new version of pipenv that was causing this problem and circle still uses it, pipenv has released a new relase today, June 2nd `2020.6.2` which fixes the problem, I just added

```
pip install pipenv==2020.6.2
```

to circle config and builds are working again

EDIT: if you use cache within circleci you must explicitely uninstall the version coming from the circle docker image first or it will still fail

```
pip uninstall pipenv -y
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: if you are using cache you could have still problems, updated my answer :)

Comment: I had issues, I came to check this again, saw your update, implemented it, and it fixed it. Thanks for the addition. :)